# how to show only one message in validation summary at a time asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

```
<div id="dvErrorMessagesProfile" style="padding-top:2px; margin: 0 auto; width:540px;">
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"
        ValidationGroup="vgProfile" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" Display="none" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="<div class='error_box_login'>please enter first name.<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='hideValid(this);'  class='error-cross'></a>  </div>"
        ControlToValidate="FirstName" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgProfile"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLastName" Display="none" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="<div class='error_box_login'>please enter last name.<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='hideValid(this);'  class='error-cross'></a>  </div>"
        ControlToValidate="LastName" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgProfile"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddressLine1" Display="none" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="<div class='error_box_login'>Please enter address line 1.<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='hideValid(this);'  class='error-cross'></a>  </div>"
        ControlToValidate="AddressLine1" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgProfile"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCity" Display="none" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="<div class='error_box_login'>please enter city.<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='hideValid(this);'  class='error-cross'></a>  </div>"
        ControlToValidate="City" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgProfile"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvZip" Display="none" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="<div class='error_box_login'>please enter Zip.<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='hideValid(this);'  class='error-cross'></a>  </div>"
        ControlToValidate="Zip" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgProfile"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I want to show only first message of validation summery. mean If user not enter any value then it shows only 1st message other are not shown etc...

Comment: Do you don't want second message ?

Comment: I want but i want to display 1 message at atime

Comment: Validation summary should be display all validation messages , if you must need to show one message, then you can use jquery alert or popup !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValidationSummary is what it's name says - a summary of validations. I'm not aware of any pre-built attritube or something that would let you pick the message you want to show.

You have basically few options

- create a custom control
- use jquery/javascript/... validation and control it from there
- create a Label or something and control the shown message from your C# code